# How to do split on typeScript

Tags: html, typescript, dom

I expect to select the last number from the String , it is 1 for example from [1 sur 1].

I tried to get the last number :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("mat-paginator-range-label")[0].valueOf().outerText.split(" ").splice(-1) ;
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="mat-paginator-range-actions"><div class="mat-paginator-range-label">1 sur 1</div>
```

Comment: HTML code : <div class="mat-paginator-range-actions"><div class="mat-paginator-range-label">1 sur 1</div>

Comment: Seems to work as is? It returns your array with ["1"] in it? If you need only the value, then use `document.getElementsByClassName("mat-paginator-range-label")[0].valueOf().outerText.split(" ").splice(-1)[0]`

Comment: I have the result with DOM, I need to do the same with Angular

Comment: What is your question? You mention TypeScript, have tagged typescript, but then mention Angular? What are you looking for?

Comment: Yes , I need to do the same code for Typescript on an Angular project.

Answer (score 0):

there are n number of ways to do it.
plain and old way is this

```
let splitArr = document.getElementsByClassName("mat-paginator-range-label")[0].valueOf().outerText.split(" ");
let myContent = splitArr[splitArr.length -1];
```

Comment: La propriété 'outerText' n'existe pas sur le type 'Object' . This is the error message.

Comment: I'm looking to do something like this : getNombrePage() {
    return  document.getElementsByClassName('.mat-paginator-range-label').valueOf().outerText.split(' ').splice(-1) as HTMLElement;
   }